# How to sort vuesax table component data in descending order by default?

Tags: sorting, vue.js

I am trying to sort my vuesax table component data in descending order by default and display. But by default its in ascending order and while clicking the header Id in the table, its getting sorted in descending by the help of sort-key property in vuesax. Can anyone help me to change this by default to descending order. My scripting's are in Vue.Js

My Vuesax table component code

```
 <template slot="thead">
    <vs-th sort-key="id">Id</vs-th>
    <vs-th sort-key="first_name">Name</vs-th>
 </template>

<template slot-scope="{data}">
  <tbody>
    <vs-tr :data="tr" :key="indextr" v-for="(tr, indextr) in data">
       <vs-td>
        <p class="product-name font-medium truncate">{{ tr.id }}</p>
       </vs-td>  
     </vs-tr>
  </tbody>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll find your answer here: https://eslint.vuejs.org/rules/sort-keys.html.

In your main.js file, you should have Vuesax imported already. If not, you can do the following and add the relevant options (from the link above):

```
import Vuesax from 'vuesax'
import 'vuesax/dist/vuesax.css'

Vue.use(Vuesax, {
  // options here
})
```